# Django and Python + uWSGI

Tags: python, django, nginx, wsgi, uwsgi

Using [instruction](http://library.linode.com/lemp-guides/debian-5-lenny/#deploy_python_code_with_wsgi_and_uwsgi) I try to connect **Python** + **uWSGI**.

I made default project in a folder **/home/sanya/django/pasteurl**.
However, have opened it in a browser I get

```
uWSGI Error
wsgi application not found
```

Logs contain the following:

```
binding on TCP port: 9001
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 64 connections
added /home/sanya/django/pasteurl to pythonpath.
initializing hooks...done.
...getting the applications list from the 'django' module...
uwsgi.applications dictionary is not defined, trying with the "applications" one...
applications dictionary is not defined, trying with the "application" callable.
static applications not defined, you have to use the dynamic one...
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 7637)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 7646)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 7647)
spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 7648)
spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 7649)
```

File **/home/sanya/django/pasteurl/django.wsgi**

```
import os
import django.core.handlers.wsgi

# init django settings
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'pasteurl.settings'

# define wsgi app
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()

# mount this application at the webroot
# applications = { '/': 'application' }
```

As I realised, it's something wrong with this **application** dictionary

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, looking at the [source code](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/browser/uwsgi.c?rev=335:d3e73a6643d9), starting at line 1997, we see that uWSGI emits the exact sequence of error messages that you are receiving if it cannot find an `applications` dictionary.

Looking at your `django.wsgi` file, we see that the line,

```
`applications = {'/': 'application'}
```

is commented out. I wonder what we could do about that ;)

BTW, I found the source code using [google](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&ie=UTF-8&q=static+applications+not+defined,+you+have+to+use+the+dynamic+one...#hl=en&expIds=17259,23320,24813,25941,25980,26751,26758&sugexp=ldymls&tok=9wC51V2nrMDnQvsMmo1B5A&xhr=t&q=%22static+applications+not+defined,+you+have+to+use+the+dynamic+one...%22&cp=69&pf=p&sclient=psy&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=%22static+applications+not+defined%2C+you+have+to+use+the+dynamic+one...%22&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=1de331493393b8ab). Googling for error messages in quotes is often a good thing to do. After I clicked on that link and realized that I was lucky enough to have found the source code straight from google (happens more and more), I pressed Ctrl-F for 'find on page' and re-entered the error message in my browser's on page search facility which led me straight to the relevant lines.

Comment: I commented it out because nothing changed. I think I tried everything. Source code also didn't help me.

Answer (score 1):

same issue, remark here:

```
uWSGI Error
wsgi application not found
```

check nginx conf:

```
uwsgi_param UWSGI_CHDIR  somepath
wsgi_param UWSGI_SCRIPT  somefile
```

make sure:

1.sompath/somefile.py  must exist

2.it must use ".py" as extent file name

3.don't use full name such as "somefile.py",  or same error happend ocer, and has error log in uwsgi log file:

```
ImportError: No module named py
```